# How do you start a java servlet over https?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ssl

I am trying to run a servlet on tomcat in eclipse. When i do run on server, the servlet runs and provides me with a link like follows:

"http://localhost:8443/AuthServer/Server"

I have configured my Tomcat server for SSL as follows:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="C:\Users\owner\.keystore" keystorePass="sheetalkshirsagar">
```

When I run the servlet on server it still uses http.
I want my link to the servlet to be "https://..." instead of "http://..". How do you do that?

Comment: Can you post your entire server.xml file?

Comment: @dash1e, his `Connector` setup is correct. Read my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be sure to use the https protocol when you send request to that servlet you need to change the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file in your web application.
In your case add this configuration params:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>AuthServer</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/Server</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 4):

In `TOMCAT_HOME/conf` folder, there’s a file named `web.xml`. In there, you have to add a `security-constraint` element.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secured page</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/...</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Make sure that `<url-pattern>` matches your path that you want to be secured.

Comment: Do not change that param on global `web.xml` or it will be valid for every tomcat application that runs on that Tomcat. But use the `web.xml` under `WEB-INF` of your application.

Comment: @dash1e, consider reading my last statement on my post. Yes, you can add it on your `WEB-INF/web.xml`, but the OP wants to configure Tomcat to do it.

Comment: Setting it inside the WEB-INF/web.xml IS configuring Tomcat to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are publishing a URL for `http` from a web page served by your servlet.
If you need to change the request to be `https` instead you should `redirect` your plain `http` connector (in port `80` or `8080` where you have it) to connector for port `443`.
If you google `tomcat redirect http to https` you wil find plenty of links e.g. [redirect tomcat to https](http://krangsquared.blogspot.com/2007/09/set-up-tomcat-to-redirect-http-requests.html)

But I would recomend that you did not redirect if you are interested in real security