# How to set up Apache Tomcat 8 to run a servlet application on HTTPS

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I want to run my servlet on HTTPS instead of HTTP, so I followed the instructions on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10092819/303685) and made the following changes to the web.xml of my servlet application:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Bookyard Server</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

However, when I **Run As -> Run on Server** in Eclipse, I get the following page:

[image]

When I compose the same request in Fiddler, I see that the server returns a 502, indicating that the server is not listening on the port (8443) I use.

> HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2016
>   12:22:14 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Connection: close
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate Timestamp: 17:52:14.594
>
> [Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed. 
> Error:
>   ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 127.0.0.1:8443

And when I make a web request to this Url via code, it results in a `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` exception.

Therefore, I am obviously not setting things up correctly. Could you please help me?

**UPDATE**

After making the changes suggested in the answer provided by Nicolas Filotto, when I launch Tomcat manually by starting the `startup.bat` file in the Tomcat installation folder and then browse to `https://localhost:8443`, it gives me the invalid certificate error in the browser, and I add an exception for this URL in my browser and I see the Tomcat splash screen just fine.

But when I launch the application in Eclipse, it resorts to the old non-SSL URL and serves the page as though it were from an insecure URL.

The console window outputs this, if this may a useful hint about the error.

> Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Bookyard.server' did
>   not find a matching property. Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   built:          Jun 9 2016 13:55:50 UTC Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   number:         8.0.36.0 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Name:
>   Windows 7 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS
>   Version:            6.1 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Architecture:          amd64 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_65-b17 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Vendor:            Oracle Corporation Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Sathyaish\Practice\Java\eclipse\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
>   Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.0 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=C:\Sathyaish\Practice\Java\eclipse\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
>   Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.0 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument:
>   -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Sathyaish\Practice\Java\eclipse\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
>   Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent INFO: The
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>   performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files\Trend
>   Micro\AMSP;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Smart
>   Projects\IsoBuster;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
>   SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform
>   Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\;C:\Users\computer.dnx\bin;C:\Users\computer\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Sathyaish\Software\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
>   Aug 29, 2016 6:47:16 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Aug 29, 2016 6:47:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Aug 29, 2016 6:47:17 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Aug 29, 2016 6:47:17 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector INFO:
>   Using a shared selector for servlet write/read Aug 29, 2016 6:47:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 2448 ms Aug 29, 2016 6:47:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Aug 29, 2016 6:47:17 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 Aug 29, 2016 6:47:19 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
>   INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation
>   using [SHA1PRNG] took [283] milliseconds. Aug 29, 2016 6:47:20 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] Aug 29, 2016 6:47:20 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] Aug 29, 2016 6:47:20 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   2920 ms

Comment: This setting is not done in your project (like the web.xml is) but rather in the configuration of the tomcat server. Check your tomcat installation folder for a ``conf/server.xml``.

Answer (score 2):

You have also to uncomment the connector for `https` in your file `conf/server.xml`:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Simply follow this [guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) as you will also need to create a certificate and add the related attributes to your connector's configuration.

At the end, it should look like something like this:

```
<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="150"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/path/to/my/keystore" keystorePass="My keystore password"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Comment: What about a certificate?  Shouldn't one be added?  Hopefully not self-signed.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thank you. I followed the steps in the article linked, generated a key, updated the `<Connector>` for SSL ports as you mention, but I still get a 502 back from the server when I start my application.

Comment: have you checked your log files to see of there is a configuration issue somewhere?

Comment: also try to launch tomcat manually instead of through eclipse to see if there is a difference

Comment: @NicolasFilotto When I launch Tomcat manually using the `startup.bat` file in the installation folder, and then browse to `https://localhost:8443`, it gives me that invalid certificate error in the browser, and then if I add localhost as an exception, I get to the Tomcat start page alright, but when I shut down the server and launch it via Eclipse, it resorts back to the old non-SSL 8080 port url.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the console output.

Comment: The server log files haven't been written to in the last week.

Comment: there is something wrong with your configuration as there is no message of type "INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]"

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233263/eclipse-modify-server-xml-each-time-run-the-project-run-run-on-server